# How to write a Mod Rewrite to exclude Shibboleth urls?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shibboleth

I have a wordpress site with Shibboleth plugin installed, Which uses Shibboleth to authenticate users.

Site url : www.mytestsite.com/wordpress/blog

I wanted to remove the subdirectory from the url so, I followed the below url and accomplished it

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Now, I can access the blog without the subdirectory

Site url : www.mytestsite.com/blog

The htaccess file looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but now shibboleth authentication does not work because apache is tring to find shibboleth urls in wordpress and displays page is not found.

I'll need to write a RewriteCond which would exclude shibboleth urls.

the shibboleth url are:

www.mytestsite.com/Shibboleth.sso/Login

www.mytestsite.com/Shibboleth.sso/Logout

www.mytestsite.com/Shibboleth.sso/Session

I need help in writing the RewriteCond rule for the above urls, kindly help.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.sso/` after the first rule, but before the second rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, (as per my comment under question):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.sso/ # exclude Shibboleth extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

...add another condition to the second RewriteRule group, excluding requests that contain a dot-s-s-o-forward slash. :)

Comment: hi could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/q/28948418/4119732 it is an additional rule, I want to add in the .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ignore Shibboleth.sso and index.php from rewrite
RewriteRule ^index\.php|Shibboleth\.sso$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```