# Mod Rewirte for CalDav and CardDav urls in Owncloud

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, owncloud

I want to shorten my owncloud caldav and carddav urls.

currently the urls are :

https://site.mysite.com/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/principals/edison/

https://site.mysite.com/owncloud/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/edison/contacts

Note : The name edison and what ever follows after that is dynamic it will change depending on the users.

I want it to be

https://site.mysite.com/caldav/principals/edison/

https://site.mysite.com/carddav/addressbooks/edison/contacts

```
.htaccess file contains 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.sso/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Eg:

If the user request for https://site.mysite.com/caldav/principals/edison/ . Then it should redirect to https://site.mysite.com/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/principals/edison/

How can it be done using mod_rewrite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mod_rewrite Prepend Path to Requested URL with Dynamic Portion**

Starting at server root, enter the requested URL path in the `RewriteRule` "pattern" parameter, and the desired path in the "substitution" parameter. In the form:

```
RewriteRule pattern substitution [flags]
```

In this case:

```
RewriteRule ^caldav/principals/edison/$ owncloud/remote.php/caldav/principals/edison/ [L]
```

If a portion of the URL (between slashes) varies and you don't want to (or can't) write a rule for every situation then use the regular expression `([^/]+)` to capture the dynamic portion and inject it into your substituted path using the RE capture variable `$1`:

```
RewriteRule ^caldav/principals/([^/]+)/$ owncloud/remote.php/caldav/principals/$1/ [L]
```

The first set of parenthesis is `$1`, the second set is `$2`, etc. And capturing parenthesis can be nested.

Put the more specific rules higher in the rules list, and more general rules lower in the list. So I suggest putting this rule first, right after `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: RewriteRule ^caldav/principals/edison/$ owncloud/remote.php/caldav/principals/edison/ [L] - The name edison is not static its dynamic it keeps changing according to the user.

Comment: Add the fact that "edison" is not static to your question.

Comment: No, I didn't get an error. I just want to add owncloud/remote.php to the url. If the url contains /caldav/ or /carddav/

Comment: Thank you. I used (.*) to get remain part of the url as the remain part remains to be more dynamic. This is what I used: RewriteRule ^caldav/(.*)$ site.mysite.com/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/$1 [L] and RewriteRule ^carddav/(.*)$ site.mysite.com/owncloud/remote.php/carddav/$1 [L]